# scroliIntoview jQuery plugin does not doing anything

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm currently using the plugin scrollintoview from https://github.com/litera/jquery-scrollintoview and is not working, the plugin is ready when I tested out with jQuery.scrollintoview.

Also tested other plugins for scrolling and also not working.

Here is my js function:

```
function scrollToId(id){
  $('#'+id).scrollintoview({
    duration: 1000,
    direction: 'vertical',
    complete: function () {
      console.log('Ready');
    }
  });
}
```

And here is the order of the js files in the index.html

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-scrollintoview/1.8/jquery.scrollintoview.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/index/index.js"></script>
```

One example in the use of this function is `<button onclick="goToId('design')" ><h5>Design</h5></button>`
That should be going up to `<div id="design"><h1>Design</h1></div>`
And the console is not printing any error.

Also tested with the plugin scrollTo from https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo but it has the same behavior.

Comment: Are you seeing errors in your console? Where are you calling `scrollToId(id)`?

Comment: I'm calling it in buttons and other functions that works well, the function is called correctly, the problem is the jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin doesn't work when you are using the overflow-y:hidden property in the body style: `<body style="overflow-y:hidden;">`